# Cost of namespaces

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

What is the cost of defining namespaces in c++? By that I specifically mean compile-time/run-time increase, and/or memory footprint. Let's say I have trivial program with a header file and a .cpp with main. Would I notice a change in these aforementioned statistics if I, say, define a `namespace` in my header? What about 10, 100, or 1,000 namespaces? What if they are defined but never used: does that change the answer? I guess you could say I'm curious how this construct interacts with the compiler(s).

Similarly, I am curious about the effect of `struct`/`class` definitions and `using`, but I couldn't think of a good title for a question encompassing all three.

Comment: It might increase compile time, it has no effect on run time as it is all compiled away.

Comment: You should probably read about name mangling. Even if release executable files ship without debug symbols namespace names will still add up to import / export table size and will cause executable to consume more space.

Comment: There is a theoretical run time cost: the mangled names are kept in the binary, and therefore are in memory at runtime. More namespace nesting = longer mangled names = more memory used = more cache misses = slower... However, I would be hugely surprised if you managed to measure this difference even with pathological nesting.

Comment: `compile-time` zero (in practice), `run-time` zero, `memory footprint` for dll-s almost zero (symbols have longer names), for lib/application zero (in release mode).

Comment: @BoBTFish mangled names may be kept in binary, it is completely optional

Comment: @BoBTFish longer mangled names do not have impact how function is called. Only when mangled names are used this can have some impact on speed and this happens only when searching for symbols in dll-s, or system creates a crash log.

Comment: If you created a header file that is 10 GB of namespaces being opened and closed, it would of course increase compile time - if only because the compiler has to work through 10 GB of text.

Similarly, if there was a platform where mangled symbols could be up to 10 GB in length, then your executable might take longer to run because the mangled symbol names are part of the binary (or at least a library) and thus it takes longer for the binary to be loaded from memory.

**But none of this really matters in the grand scheme of things.** C++ compilation is slow for other reasons.

Comment: If you are concerned about compilation times in C++, you might want to look at [the rule of Chiel](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6gur2x/the_rule_of_chiel_aka_compiletime_cost_of/) and [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Faster Builds](https://slides.com/onqtam/faster_builds/fullscreen#/1).

Answer (score 10):

> What is the cost of defining namespaces in c++?

You have to write longer names<sup>†</sup>. This cost is offset by the fact that name conflicts are avoided across different namespaces. A short name is of no use if the name has a conflict.

<sup>†</sup>Not really though: A namespace lets you get off with less writing, since you don't always need to retype the namespace into unqualified identifiers.

> By that I specifically mean compile-time

Potentially marginally.

> run-time increase

None in practice.

> Would I notice a change in these aforementioned statistics if I, say, define a namespace in my header?

You can find out by measuring.

You probably won't notice.

Comment: Runtime can increase where runtime type information (RTTI aka `typeid`) or debug symbols  (e.g. printing function names during stack trace) or compiler's `__FUNCTION__` macro are used.

Comment: @BenVoigt It might also increase because you expended more energy typing them out, thereby increasing the temperature of your room (and the entire universe), thereby reducing the thermal heat ceiling of your (and anyone else's) CPU. This is all pretty nonsensical if you ask me.

Comment: @BenVoigt Would `yes_ns::unique` be much bigger symbol than `no_ns_unique` though?

Comment: @eerorika: Your own answer asserts, in the first sentence, that names are longer in the namespace version.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Yes, looking at 14th-order effects is non-sensical.  That doesn't make it silly to look at second-order effects.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah. But I'm being snide in that part of my answer :)

Comment: @BenVoigt The time for copying/printing out function name lengths is still an absolutely insignificant part of obtaining a stack trace. Similarly, all the other things you mention are only about the size of the strings that are stored in the binary somewhere. Does any real-world application really spend significant amounts of time processing results of `typeid` or the values of `__FUNCTION__` expansions? I don't believe it (and if it does, it's clearly got much bigger design problems). Without a concrete example I think it's as relevant as my entropy consideration.

Answer (score 4):

> By that I specifically mean compile-time

Namespace can significantly reduce compile times since the compiler may have less overload to check when using a function.

This advantage is lost when using `using namespace xyz;`

Further compile time improvement can be done by using friend functions instead of free function, since ADL will have even less overload to check (in case of operators or if you already were using ADL)

Comment: Can you provide some paper/measurements to support that. I'm not saying that you are wrong, but I wonder how this is possible. Overloads are so rare that even if you are right impact should not be measurable. Also when you do not use namespace, usually some prefixes are used, so "overload argument" is also not valid.

Comment: You are also not taking into account all the extra work the compiler has to take in maintaining the namespaces used and whats in them.

Comment: How much is *significantly*? Also, don't the namespaces also increase compile time (perhaps marginally) of unqualified lookups in the case when the overload is found in the global namespace?

Comment: @MarekR I could write a blog post or something, I didn't thought about sharing my result. I might do that when I'm less busy. However I think most of my gains were when moving free function into friend functions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help it, but here is a real-life (although anecdotal) example of real cost of namespaces.

Several years ago I was working in a major company with very strong technological presence (no more would be said about them here). One of the distinctive aspects of their codebase was that it was dominantly server-side, Unix binaries **compiled in 32 bit mode**. One of the coding conventions used in the company was that **every** name should have been put in 3 nested namespaces - the rather long company name namespace, followed by 3 character name namespace, and than another one of 5 characters. (There were exceptions for legacy code).

The codebase was huge (as in **linking** of the executable would take up to 15 minute on a very powerful machine) and they were coming to the natural limit of executable size for 32 bit. Coming quickly - the new code was added, and the doom limit approached. A lot of solutions were discussed in a fire-sale urgency mode, and the one was that if we just used the shorthand for company name in the namespace, and may be used less characters in nested namespaces, we would postpone the doom of 32 bit limitation by several months!

Full disclosure - I do not know how this sutuation was resolved, I left the company before doomsday.

Comment: Are you sure that the lengthy linking time was caused by the namespaces though?

Comment: Replace all namespace scope resolution operators with underscores and get that limit much faster; inside a namespace local names are used and cut the costs. I doubt that the code would even compile - due to global namespace exhaustion.

Comment: @eerorika no, I never meant to say that, if it made sound like that I wasn't clear enough. The lengthy linking time was caused by the amount of code linked in, I highlight this fact to show how big codebase was.